# How get 1 row from join 2 table where a.user_id = 'aa' and order by the last time

Tags: mysql

I have 2 table, example

TABEL_AA

```
id   uid   user_id   name   date
1    A11      aa     BBBB   2017-01-01 00:01:01
2    A13      aa     cccc   2017-01-01 00:01:05
```

TABEL_BB (temporary)

```
id   uid   user_id   name   date
1    A12      aa     BBBB   2017-01-01 00:01:02
2    A14      aa     cccc   2017-01-01 00:01:08
```

and from the 2 table i get 1 the last row, where user_id = 'aa' and ORDER BY date DESC

and the result is from TABEL BB

```
id   uid   user_id   name   date
2    A14      aa     cccc   2017-01-01 00:01:08
```

so also conversely.. if the last record is in TABEL AA

I use this query but always getting error:

```
"SELECT 
    'a.uid' 
 FROM TABEL_AA a 
    LEFT JOIN TABLE_BB b ON a.user_id = b.user_id 
 WHERE a.user_id = 'aa' LIMIT 1 ORDER BY date DESC";
```

Error :

```
"Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY date DESC' at line 1"
```

thank you for help..

Comment: please post the error you are getting.

Comment: @Rajat Mishra this my error "Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY date DESC' at line 1"

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: If you want to order something, this needs to be inside result set.

Comment: It looks like you want to get the latest row, no matter the table it is placed in, right?

Comment: @febriit limit should come after order by

Comment: @Bustkiller , yes..right

Comment: @RajatMishra, oh thank you, sory but my query seems indeed wrong. and stell geting error.

Comment: a.uid should not be in quotes and date in your query is ambiguous - qualify it with the appropirate alias. I also think your query is wrong and there should be a union in there - see Rakesh's second solution

Comment: date is a reserved word, quote it and prefix with table name,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your query is wrong, Always use limit at end of query and don't use quote in select like 'a.uid', Here is modified query:-

```
"SELECT 
    a.uid 
 FROM TABEL_AA a 
    LEFT JOIN TABLE_BB b ON a.user_id = b.user_id 
 WHERE a.user_id = 'aa' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Also your query looks wrong for what you are asking and have data, My believe it should be:-

```
select uid FROM
(Select * from TABEL_AA 
UNION
Select * from TABEL_BB) result 
order by date desc limit 1
```

Comment: Even this is true, it's not the issue.

Comment: then what is issue, as your error log shows issue near 'ORDER BY date DESC'

Comment: Needs a where user_id = 'aa'?

Comment: @RakeshKumar what is the  'result' after TABEL_BB)? it is alias?

Comment: Yes result is an alias

Comment: yes result is alias to this set (Select * from TABEL_AA 
UNION
Select * from TABEL_BB )

Answer (score 1):

You need to join your tables before sorting, and use limit:

```
select * from table_aa union select * from table_bb
where `user_id` = 'aa'
order by date_whatever desc
limit 1
```

I have renamed your `date` column to `date_whatever`, as `date` is a reserved word in MariaDB.

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6656e/9) to try this answer

Comment: aa should be in quotes not escaped.

Comment: @Bustikiller .. Thankyou